# Matlab, cosines of the angles θj between a query vector q and the document vectors aj

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I am attempting to find The cosines of the angles θj between a query vector q and the document vectors aj in which j refers to the column number.

[image: Formula]

Here is the formula, I am attempting to write in matlab. 
And here is my attempt at the code thus far:

```
    cosval = (R(:,i)'*(v(Q(:,i))'))./(norm(v)*norm(R(:,i)));
```

And the issue I am running into:

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

And here are the two matrices I am attempting this with: The matrices are separated by the line, sorry for my poor paint skills. Could the issue I am having be because my matrices do not consist of real integers or is this just the way matlab displays matrices and the issue is with my calculations line?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you define `i` ? Are the pictured matrices `R` and `Q`? We need more information to answer fully.

The most likely problem I can see is it appears you're using values from `Q` as subscript indices for `v`, which makes no sense if those values are not integers: you can't have the 5.774th entry in a vector. Going by the formula posted and assuming `Q` is a matrix it looks more likely that you want to write `R(:,i)'*(Q'*v)`, although I don't know what the capital A subscript means in your formula.

Alternatively, if you haven't assigned a variable `i`, it could be that matlab is interpreting it as the imaginary unit.  Either error would lead to the complaint about indices needing to be 'real positive integers'.